# Bootstrap bottom scrollable navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a simple question which i searched the web and cannot find the answer. I created a bootstrap responsive bottom navbar. When I list many things using the `<li>`tag, after the space is over in the first line in the navbar, it creates another line. Instead, how to make a bottom fixed navbar which is only one like and can be scrolled within the line. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: Give us some code than we can better help you

Comment: @MarioKurzweil thank you sir, my problem is already solved. Check out the 1st answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your navbar has HTML like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">Link</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Link</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Link</li>
</ul>
```

The following CSS rule will make each list item inline:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. rep ++ thanks again